# What is the area of a function $z = \frac{1}{2}y+4$ over a triagular region?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

What is the area of a function $z = \frac{1}{2}y+4$ over a triagular region given by points $A(0,-1)$, $B(3,-1)$ and $C(3,2)$?

I've tried two different approaches but came to a different results, where is my mistake?

$(1)$ Since the function is flat, I parametrized the region on the function, call it $\phi$:$$x = s$$ $$y=t$$ $$z=\frac{1}{2}t+4$$ where $s \in (0,3)$ and $t \in (-1, s-1)$.

I came to an integral $$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{-1}^{s-1}1  \left \Vert\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s} × \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \right\Vert \,dt \,ds= \int_{0}^{3} \int_{-1}^{s-1}1 \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \,dt \,ds= \frac{9\sqrt{5}}{4}$$

$(2)$ I used surface integral over the function:
$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{-1}^{x-1}(\frac{1}{2}y+4) \sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}})^2 \,dy \,dx= \int_{0}^{3} \int_{-1}^{x-1}(\frac{1}{2}y+4) \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \,dy \,dx=9\sqrt{5}.$$
What is my mistake and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is the following triangle

[image]

we have that the area of the surface defined by $f(x,y)=4+\frac{y}{2}$ over $T$ is given by
$$ \iint_{T} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2}\,dx\,dy =\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\mu(T)=\frac{9\sqrt{5}}{4}.$$

Comment: What does $\mu (T)$ represent and why should I not integrate the function as well?

Comment: $\mu(T)$ is the Lebesgue measure (the area) of $T$, i.e. $\frac{9}{2}$. The surface is the integral of the surface element, see the last formula in the first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral.